# Compiling and linking libev on Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos

Yet another symbol(s) not found issue with Mac OS X. I wrote a C program that uses the libev event loop library that when compiled produces this output:

```
$ make
clang midnight.c midnight_logging.c -o midnight
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ev_default_loop", referenced from:
      _main in midnight-Wlcawk.o
  "_ev_io_start", referenced from:
      _main in midnight-Wlcawk.o
  "_ev_run", referenced from:
      _main in midnight-Wlcawk.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [midnight] Error 1
```

I used homebrew to install libev. The shared library is in /usr/local/lib per normal and I've used every combination of compiler arguments including "-I /usr/local/lib", "-l libev" and "-L /usr/local/lib".

Assistance appreciated, I'd rather not have to statically compile.

Comment: I don't see a `-lev` in the compiler invocation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But you ***do not*** link against libev! The compiler isn't a clairvoyant (nor is the linker), you have to tell it what to search for those symbols...

```
clang midnight.c midnight_logging.c -o midnight -lev
```